# Save user Current Location

Tags: java, android

Hello in this code first i check if GPS can get location and save that location 
lat and long then if GPS cant get location check if there is any saved location and set lat and long from the saved finally if there is no saved set location to
  latitude  = 56.130366; longitude = -106.346771;

```
      if(gps.canGetLocation()) {

        latitude  = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putFloat(LATITUDE,  (float) latitude);
        editor.putFloat(LONGITUDE, (float) longitude);
        editor.putBoolean("IsNotEmpty", true);
        editor.apply();
    }

    else {

            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            if (prefs.getBoolean("IsNotEmpty",true)) {
                latitude  = (double) prefs.getFloat(LATITUDE, 0);
                longitude = (double) prefs.getFloat(LONGITUDE, 0);
            }
            else {
                latitude  = 56.130366;
                longitude = -106.346771;

            }
    }
```

Comment: Where's the problem?

Comment: _when i save the location in Shared Preferences i cant load it again where is the error in my code_. What are you trying to tell? Please elaborate the question more thoroughly and include some pictures if necessary

Comment: the problem when i open the app and the location is off and there is no saved in pref the lat and long is 0 not latitude  = 56.130366; longitude = -106.346771; @s

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your code to below:

```
else {
       SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
       latitude  = (double) prefs.getFloat(LATITUDE, 56.130366);
       longitude = (double) prefs.getFloat(LONGITUDE, -106.346771);
     }
```

This way you get rid off not required if-else block as well and more readable code.

also, if you can make use of

```
editor.commit();
```

this will save data to preference synchronously as per [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply())

Comment: ok but in latitude  = (double) prefs.getFloat(LATITUDE, 56.130366) need float not double how to use double